# How to get the app bundle id from javaScript in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, web

How can I get the `iOS` application bundle id from WebView (no matter which one) in `Javascript`.

I've tried so far to get it from the `Navigator` and `Location` objects (JS objects), but without success.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Apparently youtube can block embedding to certain mobile apps based on bundle id. Can't figure out how they are getting it